# Find Unhealthy Instances in a target group in AWS with Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to find the unhealthy instance in a target group using boto3, but there is no function which can provide.

Comment: Instances of what? EC2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code to filter the unhealthy instances of the target group. I did it whit this code on Python using LB client of boto3.

```py
import boto3
    # Initialize a boto3 client for Elastic Load Balancing
    elb_client = boto3.client('elbv2')
    # Specify your target group ARN
    target_group_arn = 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-2:208371820303:targetgroup/myapp/123456'
    # Describe the target health
    response = elb_client.describe_target_health(TargetGroupArn=target_group_arn)
    #print('Response from elb client: ',response)
    
    unhealthy_instances = []
    healthy_instances = []
    other_state_instances = []
    
    #Evaluate the health state of each instance in the response by iterating
    for instance in response['TargetHealthDescriptions']:
        if (instance['TargetHealth']['State'] == 'unhealthy'):
            unhealthy_instances.append(instance['Target']['Id'])
        elif ((instance['TargetHealth']['State'] == 'healthy')):
            healthy_instances.append(instance['Target']['Id'])
        else:
            other_state_instances.append(instance['Target']['Id'])
    
    print("-------------------------------------------")
    print("Unhealthy Instances: ", unhealthy_instances)
    print("Healthy Instances: ", healthy_instances)
```

The execution should give you the next information:

[Console output of python script shows healthy and unhealthy isntances.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jheFY.png)

[Instances in my target group on AWS console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s17bs.png)